# Relation between polynomials $f$ and $g$ such that roots of $g$ are squares of roots of $f$.

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose $f$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ of degree $d$, where $\mathbb{F}_q$ denote the finite field with $q$ elements. We can assume that $q$ is odd. Now, let $\eta$ be a root of $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_{q^d}$. Now, $\eta^2 \in \mathbb{F}_{q^d}$. We further assume that  minimal polynomial of $\eta^2$, say $g$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$. My question is that can we express $g$ solely in terms of $f$? It is clear that $g(x^2)$ has $f$ as one of its irreducible factors.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

Posting something to get this started (getting late here).

---

A recurring trick is that the polynomial
$
f(x)f(-x)
$
has only even degree terms, and thus there exists a polynomial $F[x]\in\Bbb{F}_q[x]$ such that
$$F(x^2)=f(x)f(-x).$$
Therefore $F(\eta^2)=0$.

Furthermore, $\deg F=\deg f$, so if you know that $\eta$ and $\eta^2$ generate the same extension you are done – we know that $g(x)=\pm F(x)$. Observe that we haven't used the fact that the fields are finite. At least not yet.

Comment: I think I can find a duplicate later, but I'm too tired now.

Comment: What seems to play a role is that if $\deg g<deg f$, then $\eta$ and $-\eta$ are conjugates, implying that $f(-x)=f(x)$, and we again know what to do.

Comment: Is there any particular technique to capture when $\eta$ and $-\eta$ are  non-conugates, or when there are conjugate?