# If $g(x)$ is a monic polynomial of degree 3 such that the roots of $g(x)=0$ are the squares of roots of $x^3+x+1=0$ then which of following true

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $g(x)$ be a monic polynomial of degree three such that the roots of $g(x)=0$ are the squares of roots $P(x)=x^3+x+1=0$. Find g(x)

**My approach**

Assuming the three roots of $P(x)$ as $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, and taking $g(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ and putting in $\alpha^2$ as a root in $g(x)$. You can reduce the power of $\alpha$ by putting it back through $P(x)$ through which I got a relation $$\alpha^2(1+b-a)+\alpha(2-a)+c=0$$ repeating this with all the three roots and adding these three equations I got the relation $$3(c+1)=2(1+b-a)$$ and we can get one more relation by applying $D=0$ on the first relation because one of the roots between $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ will be real.

I still didn't get an answer which rid me of all the 3 variables $a,b,c$ to get $g(x)$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3412992/11619). Not an ideal duplicate target, because that is specific to finite field, but the process of finding $g(x)$ mathcing a given $P(x)$ is the same. I think we have a more general one :-)

Comment: Also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1166498/11619)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate even and odd degree terms:

$x^3+x=-1$

And square:

$x^{\color{blue}6}+2x^{\color{blue}4}+x^{\color{blue}2}=1$

Note that all exponents are even, so we have a polynomial equation in $x^2$:

$(x^2)^3+2(x^2)^2+(x^2)-1=0$

This identifies the left side as $g(x^2)$ and therefore

$g(x)=x^3+2x^2+x-1.$

Comment: Wow, Great solution, learned something new

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you consider applying theory of equations

Given That $p(x)=x^3+x+1$, Let their roots be $p,q,r$

these 3 equations follow from theory of equations

$$p+q+r=0$$
$$pq+qr+pr=1$$
$$pqr=-1$$

Now let $g(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$

now the zeroes of this polynomial as per question are $p^2,q^2,r^2$

These 3 equations follow from theory of equation applied on $g(x)$

$$p^2+q^2+r^2=-a$$
$$(pq)^2+(qr)^2+(pr)^2=b$$
$$(pqr)^2=-c$$

now

$$c=-(pqr)^2=-(-1)^2=-1$$
$$a=-(p^2+q^2+r^2)=-((p+q+r)^2-2(pq+qr+pr))=-(0-2(1))=-(-2)=2$$
$$b=(pq)^2+(qr)^2+(pr)^2$$

$$(pq)^2+(qr)^2+(pr)^2=(pq+qr+pr)^2-2(q^2pr+r^2pq+p^2qr)$$

$$=(pq+qr+pr)^2-2pqr(p+q+r)$$

hence $$b=(pq+qr+pr)^2-2pqr(p+q+r)=1-2(-1)(0)=1$$

finally

$$a=2,b=1,c=-1$$

and The function $$g(x)=x^3+2x^2+x-1$$

Comment: Hmm... there shall be a mistake somewhere. I asked sympy to solve the problem and it confirmed $g(x) = x^3 + 2x^2 +x -1$

Comment: yes, Got it, the mistake was in equation of "a"